# divs positioning wrong while window resizing

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a responsive website, the problem I'm facing is with the `div`s position while re-sizing.

See I've 4 parallel `divs` but when I re-size, the fourth `div` goes below 3rd div but it should go below the 1st div.

here is the code:

```
@media(max-width: 400px){
  .one-fourth{  
    width:90%;
    padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;    /*no error here coz width is 90%*/
    float:left;
  }
}

@media (min-width:401px) and (max-width: 600px){
  .one-fourth{
    width:46%;
    padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
    float:left;
  }

}

@media (min-width:601px) and (max-width: 800px){
  .one-fourth{
    width:46%;
    padding:5px 10px 5px 10x;
    float:left;
  }
}

@media (min-width:801px)  and (max-width: 1100px){
  .one-fourth{ 
    width:29%;
    padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
    float:left;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1101px){
  .one-fourth{
    width:22%;
    padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
    float:left;
  }
}
```

html >

```
<div id="bottom">
<div class="one-fourth">
<h3>Facebook</h3>lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum 
lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum 
lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum
</div>
<div class="one-fourth">
<h3>Twitter</h3>lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum 
lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum 
lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum
</div>
<div class="one-fourth">
<h3>Instagram</h3>lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum 
lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum 
lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum
</div><div class="one-fourth">
<h3>Linkedin</h3>lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum 
lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum 
lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please creat a jsFiddle reproducing the problem.

Comment: try providing html as well or fiddle it

Comment: Off topic but are you really sure that you want to maintain 5 different media queries ? That gonna be tough

Comment: html code added 
css for #bottom{
 margin-top:5px;
}

Comment: @Oliboy50 Added the 5th one while trying to get rid of this problem.

Comment: here is working example [**example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/riaFd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your height. Like in example:

```
@media(max-width: 400px){
  .one-fourth{
    height:250px;
    width:90%;
    padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
    float:left;
  }
}
```

I tested it in the Codepen example you gave us. It should work.

Comment: height gives a lot of empty space below 3rd and 4th div and footer on tab n phones isn't there any other solution ?

Comment: This is because the 250px. Lower it. Maybe 150 should be enough.

Comment: Or make a new Id/class for different divs

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any html here but padding might be the problem here.

Try setting your padding all to 5px and check if this solves your issue:

```
padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
```

Comment: still facing the same problm

Comment: Can we see your css for ID "bottom".

Comment: #bottom{ margin-top:5px; } 
that's it.. One thing I noticed 4th div is going below 3rd div because the content in 3rd div is less than 1 and 2. i.e text in div 1 and 2 is equal and in 3rd div is less than the first two